# Publishing ivy file without jar

Tags: ant, ivy

I have a "parent" module in multimodule ant+ivy project. It's only purpose is to provide parent ivy module for other projects. No other artifacts are produced:

```
<info organization="com.example" module="parent" revision="1.0" />
<publications>
  <artifact type="ivy" />
</publications>
```

Yet when I try publishing such project, ivy attempts to publish `parent.jar`.

```
<echoproperties prefix="ivy.artifacts" />
<ivy:publish resolver="staging" />
```

Echoproperties confirms that publication declaration was at least processed:

```
[echoproperties] ivy.artifact.1.conf=default, compile, test
[echoproperties] ivy.artifact.1.ext=ivy
[echoproperties] ivy.artifact.1.name=parent
[echoproperties] ivy.artifact.1.type=ivy
```

while publish fails:

```
java.io.IOException: missing artifact com.example#parent;1.0!parent.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the [publications section](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/publications.html) of an ivy file doesn't list the ivy file, it's assumed this is automatically published. It does appear that you're picking up the default type for a published artifact, which would be a jar :-(

I'm assuming you're doing this in order to leverage the new [extends](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/extends.html) feature in the child modules? And you're trying to emulate a "pom" parent module in Maven? I wonder if it's supported by ivy...

Comment: It must've been caused by stale cache. After cleaning everything, it works with empty publication list. As for `extends` I wouldn't call it new - it's 3 years old now. Unfortunately, `<ivy:buildlist>` produces wrong ordering when using inheritance - [IVY-1427](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1427) :(

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki Fair point, the ivy project has changed very slowly. Inheritance is not a feature I plan on using with ivy. I think it make builds too complicated (A criticism I apply equally to at Maven :-)).

Comment: And my cache was stale because `<ivy:cleancache>` often silently fails on windows ([IVY-1080](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1080))